# Need to Combine two group by queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Is there any way to combine this two queries into a single query

```
SELECT siftBal.SystemName,convert(varchar(10),siftBal.Date,110) as WorkDate,SUM(siftBal.CashIn) as CashIn,SUM(siftBal.CashOut) as CashOut,
(SUM(siftBal.CashIn) - SUM(siftBal.CashOut)) as NetCash
FROM  tblShiftBalanceDetail siftBal 
WHERE siftBal.Date  between '10-28-2011' and '11-04-2011' group by convert(varchar(10),siftBal.Date,110),SystemName

SELECT  convert(varchar(10),custPlay.DatePlayed,110) as WorkDate,SUM(custPlay.TotalPoints) as EntriesIn,SUM(custPlay.TotalWin) as Payout,
(SUM(custPlay.TotalPoints)*0.01) - SUM(custPlay.TotalWin) as NetProfit, 
(SUM(custPlay.TotalWin)*100/SUM(custPlay.TotalPoints))*100 as Payout
FROM  [tblCustomerPlay] custPlay 
WHERE custPlay.DatePlayed between '10-28-2011' and '11-04-2011' group by convert(varchar(10),custPlay.DatePlayed,110)
```

Comment: The columns are different, so a UNION isn't going to work.  These data sets look quite different to me; can you elaborate on what you mean by "combine" them?  It would be helpful to show an example of what the data in the two tables looks like and what the desired outcome would look like; then someone can help you get there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the two result sets together:

```
[query 1]
UNION ALL
[query 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they have the same number and type of columns, you can use UNION:

```
select foo, bar from table1
union
select foo, bar from tabe2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    entries.EntriesIn
  , entries.NetProfit
  , entries.Payout
  , entries.Perchentage
  , siftBal.SystemName
  , siftBal.WorkDate
  , siftBal.TotalCashIn
  , siftBal.TotalCashout
  , NetCash
FROM
    ( SELECT
        shift.SystemName
      , CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), shift.Date, 110) AS WorkDate
      , SUM(shift.CashIn) AS TotalCashIn
      , SUM(shift.CashOut) AS TotalCashout
      , ( SUM(shift.CashIn) - SUM(shift.CashOut) ) AS NetCash
      FROM
        tblShiftBalanceDetail AS shift
      WHERE
        shift.Date BETWEEN '10-28-2011' AND '11-03-2011'
      GROUP BY
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), shift.Date, 110)
      , shift.SystemName ) AS siftBal
    JOIN ( SELECT
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), custPlay.DatePlayed, 110) AS WorkDate
          , SUM(custPlay.TotalPoints) AS EntriesIn
          , SUM(custPlay.TotalWin) AS Payout
          , ( SUM(custPlay.TotalPoints) * 0.01 ) - SUM(custPlay.TotalWin) AS NetProfit
          , ( SUM(custPlay.TotalWin) * 100 / SUM(custPlay.TotalPoints) ) * 100 AS Perchentage
           FROM
            [tblCustomerPlay] custPlay
           WHERE
            custPlay.DatePlayed BETWEEN '10-28-2011'
                                AND     '11-04-2011'
           GROUP BY
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), custPlay.DatePlayed, 110) ) entries ON entries.WorkDate = siftBal.WorkDate
```

Answer (score 0):

On the first Group query I have added blank column 'Payout' and on the second query I have added a blank column 'SystemName'.

```
SELECT  siftBal.SystemName ,
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), siftBal.Date, 110) AS WorkDate ,
            SUM(siftBal.CashIn) AS CashIn ,
            SUM(siftBal.CashOut) AS CashOut ,
            ( SUM(siftBal.CashIn) - SUM(siftBal.CashOut) ) AS NetCash,
            '' AS 'Payout'
    FROM    tblShiftBalanceDetail siftBal
    WHERE   siftBal.Date BETWEEN '10-28-2011'
                         AND     '11-04-2011'
    GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), siftBal.Date, 110) ,
            SystemName
   UNION ALL
    SELECT  '' AS 'SystemName',
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), custPlay.DatePlayed, 110) AS WorkDate ,
            SUM(custPlay.TotalPoints) AS EntriesIn ,
            SUM(custPlay.TotalWin) AS Payout ,
            ( SUM(custPlay.TotalPoints) * 0.01 ) - SUM(custPlay.TotalWin) AS NetProfit ,
            ( SUM(custPlay.TotalWin) * 100 / SUM(custPlay.TotalPoints) ) * 100 AS Payout
    FROM    [tblCustomerPlay] custPlay
    WHERE   custPlay.DatePlayed BETWEEN '10-28-2011'
                                AND     '11-04-2011'
    GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), custPlay.DatePlayed, 110)
```